# Why does CMAKE installed target fail to link to provided libraries?

Tags: cmake, installation, shared-libraries, linkage

I'm building a target that depends on some provided libraries. My src directory hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

I use the following `CMakeLists.txt` to build a target and install it within the `build/install` directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(example)

include_directories(include)
link_directories(lib)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
src/example.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
curlpp)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/install)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

install(FILES lib/libcurlpp.a  lib/libcurlpp.so  lib/libcurlpp.so.1 lib/libcurlpp.so.1.0.0 DESTINATION deps)
```

When I do a simple `build`, everything is fine and the target is properly linked to the provided libraries. But when I do `make install`, the target is generated but fails to link to the libraries:
[image]

I understand the linkage failure of the installed target: the `install/deps` directory is not in the  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` of my environment. But what has cmake done to make the directly built target link correctly? Can I do something similar to make the installed target work properly?

Here is [a minimal replication of the problem](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r-X9sx0RetBqam_rjRy685qiFtNXj7zW)

Comment: Note that link_directories(lib) will put your local lib directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Of course, the location of this lib is different when installed. Normally, you should install your libraries in a path which is by default included in LD_LIBRARY_PATH such as /usr/local/lib.

Comment: @GergelyNyiri But the directory does not appear in my global LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I think somehow it is appended to LD_LIBRARY_PATH when I run the built target (or to say, the built target somehow has a LD_LIBRARY_PATH specific to itself?). I'm wondering how cmake did this so that I can do something similar: permanently allow the installed target to find the library without changing my global LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: cmake will internally use -L<your-lib-path> in the underlying gcc/g++/ldd call. You you can export these options from cmake by setting CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS to ON. That is, the linker (?) will attach an absolute path when doing the linkage of your shared object file. If you move this so file to other than a system-wide library path, it will not be found. The solution for your issue would be to simply copy the so files in lib instead of deps.

Comment: sorry, I'm a bit lazy now to give a complete answer, but give you a hint: CMake use `RPATH` (read about it) for the locally built lib, and then strip it (on install).